# Guitar pedal blocks sound when I engage

Tags: guitar, guitar-effects, effects-pedal

i don't know if this is the right place to ask, but it's music related, so i'll give it ago.

I recently got into guitar, and i have just aquired an caline cp-68 distortion/delay pedal. I plugged the output into my Fender mustang I V.2 amp and connected the pedal to a 9 volt battery.

Plugged my guitar into the input and started playing. Everything seemed fine, until i enganged the distortion effect, the all sound stopped. I turned some of the knobs and still no sound. So i disenganged distortion and the sound came back.

Then i tried enganging the delay and the sound stopped again!

I've had the knobs on many different settings, and checked the volume on my amp, but i get no sound when i engange. Googeling doesn't bring any answers either.

Comment: "... and connected the pedal to a [decidedly unpleasant to lick?] 9 volt battery."

Answer (score 6):

With the pedal "off" your signal is routed past the effect, which is why that works.

With the pedal "on" the signal is routed into the effect so any problem with the effect will become noticeable. The problem is that over the internet we cannot see what is wrong with your pedal. It could be a fault with the effect, or possibly a cable, but I would first check the battery:

Are you getting 9 volts, and is it connected the right way round? This is easy to check, and cheap to sort out.

Check all jack connectors are seated fully - sometimes they can cause issues if not fully in. And are they connected the right way? In and Out the right way round?

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is the battery. I bought a handful of battery connectors to use for mini pedals that don't have room for a battery inside. Unfortunately, **many cheap battery adapters have the wrong polarity** since they're intended for Arduino or other electronic gadgets that are center-positive. So make sure the battery is connected with the correct center-negative polarity (for most pedals).

Answer (score 3):

Once in a while a person misunderstands how to connect a new pedal. Just to make certain it's hooked up correctly, the instrument plugs into the input connector, and the output connects to the input of the amplifier or to the input of the next in line foot pedal effect. If things are plugged in backwards, the effect will not pass the signal when the effect is switched in. Also, double check the battery, if it has lost it's charge, the effect won't work. If these two items check out okay, you should have a qualified technician take a look at it.
Well, I just looked online, and I noticed the pedal calls for a reversed polarity power supply and it needs to be purchased separately, this leads me to think there could be a problem with the way you are connecting the battery. You probably need to double check that connection also. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Set both “Gain” and  “Level” to 12 o’ clock and then engage the distortion. If you hear something when it’s not engaged but nothing when it’s engaged, it could mean any or a combination of the following...

1. Dead Battery - Replace battery
2. Battery to plug cable issue - try another cable
3. Pedal electronics issue - RMA

If you do hear something, Gain will control how distorted the output signal will be, Level will control how loud the output signal will be.